# Is there any way to check does list exists without try catch?

Tags: list, performance

Now i'm using same way to check does list exist by url

```
SPList logList  = null;
try
{
    logList     = site.RootWeb.GetListFromWebRelativeUrl("Lists/LogRecords");
}
catch { }
if (null != logList)
{DoSmt()}
```

This way isn't good at performance. Is where any safety way to check list existing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[SPWeb.Lists.TryGetList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistcollection.trygetlist.aspx) is probably what you're looking for.

So in your example:

```
logList = site.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Log Records");
```

Comment: Thank for answer! I'm afraid some admin of site can change the title of list.

Comment: @JamesLove This method uses Title of a list. If the Title is changed through UI, will this code work?

Comment: Nope, in which case you would probably want to use the `SPListCollection.GetList(Guid, Boolean)` method to retrieve by List Guid - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470839.aspx

Comment: @JamesLove as can I see the best approach is not to use this method :) As I understant the main part of  try-catch execution time is an exception handling time. In this case you will have the perfomants problem only if the list does not exist. But this situation, as a rule, is a very rare. Am I right?

Comment: Well use. Remember the point of Exception handling as a whole is to deal with exceptions you expect to arise in the running of your code. So, I would use TryGetList first, then the method that triggers and exception, and deal with it appropriatly. Don't use magic strings in the TryGetList, see if you can make it configurable somehow.

Comment: Not had enough coffee this morning. I have no idea what I meant with 'well use'...

Answer (score 1):

With a Guid of the list you should use

```
SPList list = sPwebObject.Lists.Cast<SPList>().FirstOrDefault(l => l.ID == yourGuidHere)
if (list != null) { .. }
```

or

```
if (sPwebObject.Lists.Cast<SPList>().Any(l => l.ID == yourGuidHere)) { .. }
```

---

With a Title of the list you should use

```
SPList list = sPwebObject.Lists.TryGetList(yourTitleHere);
if (list != null) { .. }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
logList = site.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Log Records");
```

Comment: Please provide more details.